# Actions on google Notifications at certain time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi I found following tutorial
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#dialogflow

And I was wondering if you can somehow also just trigger a notification after a certain time with a cloud function. Cause I do not want send them a notification when the user opt in, i want to send that notification after X minutes.

You have any idea how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) to schedule some code to be run at a later time.